# Hide Text from Onpage Search

Tags: css, html, wai-aria

Is there a reliable way to hide text from browsers onpage search capability (e.g. Ctrl+F) while remaining visible?

I would expect adding an `aria-hidden="true"` to solve the problem, but the text is still searchable by browsers.

Comment: just curious, why do you need this?

Comment: I'm adding text highlighting to a `contenteditable` div by duplicating the content and adding spans around what the user highlights.  Duplicating the content keeps the original markup clean.

Comment: Cool dude! I was just wondering man not being a hater!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable the on page search funtion with the follow javascript

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
window.addEventListener("keydown",function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 114 || (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode === 70)) { 
        e.preventDefault();
    }
})
</script>
```

Easy and works perfect

Comment: Not ideal, but it's probably my best bet. Your strategy is what Google docs, codepen, etc use to intercept onpage search.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the text into a pseudo-element using the `content` CSS property.

**HTML**

`<div class="some-div"></div>`

**CSS**

`.some-div:before { content: "unsearchable text"; }`